# Assign a link of a post to <article> that contains that post?

Tags: posts

I'm trying to figure out how can I assign the link of each post to every  item that contains it. I would like to click on  so I can go to the post page that the  was containing.

Here is the `<article>` item I'm talking about (it's in the `content.php` file):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package meptheme
 */

?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php meptheme_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'meptheme' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                get_the_title()
            ) );

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'meptheme' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php meptheme_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Here is the example: I'm on this page http://nuovomep.altervista.org/m-49
I would like to click on the first `<article>` and get addressed to http://nuovomep.altervista.org/m-49/26341

The `<a>` tag on line 17 contains the correct link: `<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
<?php
    if ( !is_singular() ) :
 echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">';
    endif;?>

 Here is your existing <article></article> codes

<?php
    if ( !is_singular() ) :
 echo '</a>';
    endif;?>
```